# Union query qry_Union with 3 queries of identical number columns formatted as FIXED with 2 decimals shows as currency in qry_Union

Tags: ms-access

i have a union query **qry_Union** that unites three queries q_1, q_2 and q_3. All three queries have identical amount column **col_Money** formatted as FIXED & 2 decimal. When I run qry_Union and exports to csv and excel col_Money comes out as Currency. I need col_Money to export as in base queries. Is there anything that could be changed in the union query to achieve this goal?

Please every assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "comes out as Currency" - has currency symbol? I cannot replicate issue. What method are you using? Provide code. What is field data type in table? Provide sample data as formatted text table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Format` to get the result you want. For example:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Format(col_Money,"0.00") As col_Amount FROM YourTable1
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, Format(col_Money,"0.00") As col_Amount FROM YourTable2
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1, Col2, Format(col_Money,"0.00") As col_Amount FROM YourTable3;
```

Comment: This worked using UNION. Thank you BobS.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark your question as answered.